# Visual Studio 2010 and Cassini web server can't make windows authentication! (Access Denied 401.2)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-authentication, cassini

How it could be difficult to make a web site which is integrated with domain authentication in visual studio!?

This is my web.config:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="xxxDomains\yyyGroup"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

This is the result:

[image]

But I think there would be a **logon dialog** which is for entering `domain_name\username` and `password`. Bu page is directed me always to the Access Denied Page without asking my username and password.

PS: I'm not belong to any domain. I want to use visual studio's web server(cassini). I will deploy the site after finishing project, I don't want to deploy project to web server in every F5 ...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I updated my answer. Was that of any help?

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you are missing is checking the box for `NTML Authentification` in your web projects properties under `Servers` in the `Web` tab.

[image]

Anyhow, I would recommend upgrading to [IIS Express 7.5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038), which is a simple and self-contained version of IIS that is optimized for developers:

- The way IIS Express treats Windows Authentication is the same as a "real" IIS instance.
- You still have the comfort of a local development server (e.g. <kbd>F5</kbd>) without deploying.
- The ASP.NET Development Server is not developed anymore by Microsoft and will be replaced by IIS Express in future releases of Visual Studio.

See also [this blog post by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) for more information on IIS Express or [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In solution explorer pane **select the Web Project and hit F4**. (not right click+properties, thats different)

In properties Pane set:
**Windows Authentication**: Enable 
**Anonymous Authentication**: Disabled

In Web.config: `<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>`

To get Username:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name OR User.Identity.Name
```

Run your project, Happy Days!